# psql import Error : invalid line number: e ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.2

I am using psql 9.6.22.
I am importing .sql dump file in psql command line. I am getting the error:
**invalid line number: e
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff**

Below is the error in log file of postgresql:
**2021-10-12 17:33:13 IST [10823-1] postgres@gm1 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff**
I dont see any line no or any table information. how can i resolve this error?
I don't have the database now so i can not again take the dump.

Comment: Please show the first 20 lines or so of the dump file (edit the question and put it there). Also, add the exact commands you ran to create and restore the dump.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in encoding. The file i used to import in ubuntu was created in windows. so it had a different encoding. using iconv package, i changed encoding of windows file to UTF-8 and then i was able to import the db.